# Can't get my page to scale right for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I have a page where all the content is within a fixed div (uses the Skrollr script) and I can't get it to properly scale for all device sizes.

I have fiddled to death with the viewport settings and I can get it to look right for iPhone portrait but then I rotate to landscape and it is cropped in to just 1/3 of the page on screen and so forth.

I just want it to fit in the screen (both width and height) with a little space around the sides, top and bottom but not to be sized right for iPhone and tiny on iPad screen.

My current viewport settings:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=.35">
```

I also have a wrapper div that centers all the content vertically and horizontally which may be relevant:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 755px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The page URL is www.studio-element.com/comptia/infographic.html

Comment: You should define device width as well in the meta tag.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that: width=devicewidth and also width=1000, etc. It will look right one place (like iPhone portrait) but horrible in another (iPhone landscape)

Comment: I read an article that said you should leave the width out to make it work right for both portrait and landscape (but its not)

Comment: Putting it all together doesn't work? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`